# Angular 2 binding in one way, modified both object

Tags: angular, typescript

Why one way binding modified both object

```
<component2  [obj]="obj1"></component2>
```

exist any form of change **obj** and not modified **obj1**. Only duplicate **obj** fix that, or exist in angular2 some way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are no two objects there. There is an input parameter for `component2`, called `obj`, and there is an object on your component (which uses `component2`), called `obj1`, which one is bound to the input of `component2`.

Comment: The code is a example, obj belongs to component2 and obj1 belongs to parent component, any modifications inside component2 will also affect to obj1,  because both have same reference, exist some way for only do one way binding, affect only obj?

Comment: Modifying obj in component2 shouldn't change obj1. Maybe you have some other bindings?

Comment: Modified obj in component2 also affect to obj1, try it

Comment: Here is a simple Plunker to demonstrate that changing the Input in child component will not modify the original object. 
https://plnkr.co/edit/B4N2wpjYQI930JvBAiO9?p=preview

Comment: add your plunker this line in component2:

Comment: Add to your plunker this line in component2:   <input value="{{obj.name}}" [(ngModel)]="obj.name">. If you only write  <input value="{{obj.name}}"> sure not change the object obj1, but you have to binding for modified obj and you will see that obj1 change too. This line in your plunker   <input value="{{obj.name}}"> not modified obj.name, try put in component component2 this: {{obj.name}} and you will see neither is modified.

Comment: Yes, but that's the antipattern of all antipatterns. In such case you should use an EventEmitter from the second component.

Comment: EventEmitter is for pass to parent any data, also you can use ViewChild, but if you pass a object to child in one way binding also modified object in component father, this is not antipattern this  happens, I think any form of fix that is make a clone of variable, and althoung you use eventemitter also modified object in component father with  [obj]="obj1".